# Split string with pattern and with two dots

Tags: javascript, node.js, split

I am having strings like following:

```
"cro.finished.v1"
"cro1.finished.v1"
"cro1.fd.v1"
"zro1.wd.v1"
...
```

and I need to split it into two strings, e.g.

`"cro.finished.v1"`

```
let str1 = "cro.finished"
let str2 = "v1"
```

I tried to split at `"v1"`, but I got `"cro.finished."` and `""`.

Any idea how can I simply do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

```js
let str = "cro.finished.v1";
let index = str.lastIndexOf(".");
let str1 = str.substring(0,index), str2 = str.substring(index+1);
console.log(str1,str2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split it using the **[`.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)** method which will give the index at which you need to split. Then you can just use **[`.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)** to split into two parts.

Below I have included a code snippet which has the list of strings you mentioned and it will split the strings into two parts as required.

```js
// You list of strings to be split at last .
let str = ["cro.finished.v1", "cro1.finished.v1", "cro1.fd.v1", "zro1.wd.v1", ];

let first_part = [],
  second_part = [];

// Loop for each element in your list of strings
// Split at last . and separate the words into two list 
str.forEach(function(el) {
  let idx = el.lastIndexOf('.');
  first_part.push(el.substring(0, idx));
  second_part.push(el.substring(idx + 1));

});

// First part separated into one array
console.log(first_part);

// Second part separated into another array
console.log(second_part);
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You could match the parts by looking for two groups, the first one with any characters, a dot outside of the group and a group without a dot.

```js
var string = "cro.finished.v1",
    [left, right] = string.match(/(^.+)\.([^\.]+$)/).slice(1);

console.log(left);
console.log(right);
```